# Change URL of pages according Dropdownlist SelectionIndexChanged event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm creating a website for my school project, which has two locations. I want to change the URL of pages according to that location on Dropdownlist SelectionIndexChanged event

Comment: What have you tried? Please add your code to the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location = yoururl. This demo may be your requirement.

```js
$('#location').on('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="location">
  <option value="" selected>Select a location</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com.vn">Google Vietnam</option>

</select>
```

Comment: i did same code but wasn't added script may be that's why it didn't work <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: please reference only one jquery version, press F12 and go to console tab to see what error